# Sending Real Time images captured using unity camera

Tags: python, c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, socket.io

server

```
private void SendImageByte()
    {
      
        image_bytes = cm.Capture();
       
    print(image_bytes.Length);
   

    if (connectedTcpClient == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // Get a stream object for writing.             
        NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream();
        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
           // string serverMessage = "This is a message from your server.";
            // Convert string message to byte array.                 
            byte[] serverMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(image_bytes.ToString());
            // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.
            
            stream.Write(serverMessageAsByteArray, 0, serverMessageAsByteArray.Length);
            Debug.Log("Server sent his message - should be received by client");
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
    }
}
```

client

```
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1755
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, port))

def receive_image():
    data = sock.recv(999999).decode('utf-8')
    print(len(data))

while True:
    receive_image()
```

here script capture images from unity camera

```
public byte[] Capture()
    {
        if(renderTexture == null)
        {
          
            // creates off-screen render texture that can rendered into
            rect = new Rect(0, 0, captureWidth, captureHeight);
            renderTexture = new RenderTexture(captureWidth, captureHeight, 24);
            screenShot = new Texture2D(captureWidth, captureHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        }

       // _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        _camera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        _camera.Render();

        // reset active camera texture and render texture
        _camera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;

        // read pixels will read from the currently active render texture so make our offscreen 
        // render texture active and then read the pixels
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        screenShot.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);
        screenShot.Apply();

        byte[] imageBytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
        //Object.Destroy(screenShot);

        //File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../"+ imagePath + "/img{counter}.png", bytes);
        //counter = counter + 1;
        return imageBytes;
    }
```

Am trying to send real-time images on Unity3D from C# to python using socket communication to be processed and return back values to unity, but the problem even the bytes length received on the client is not the same as the server. I send about 400K bytes but I receive only 13
C# is the server and python is the client

or am doing it wrong but the main goal I want to create simulator work as udacity self-driving

Comment: Are you aware that `recv()` can return less than the requested number of bytes?  It's your job to keep calling `recv()` until the _whole_ message has been received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `image_bytes.ToString()` returns what you expect and not maybe just something like `"System.Byte[]"` => 13 chars => 13 bytes.

In general why would you convert an already `byte[]` into a `string` just in order to convert it back into `byte[]` to send? I'm pretty sure you do not want to transmit binary image data using UTF-8 ... one option might be Base64 string, but still that would be quite inefficient.

Just send the raw bytes like e.g.

```
stream.Write(image_bytes, 0, image_bytes.Length);
```

And then receive until you receive that length.

A typical solution is to prepend the length of the message to send and on the receiver side actually wait until you received exactly that amount of bytes like e.g.

```
var lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(image_bytes.Length);
stream.Write(lengthBytes, 0, lengthBytes.Length);
stream.Write(image_bytes, 0, image_bytes.Length);
```

Now you know that on the receiver side you first have to receive exactly `4` bytes (== one int) which will tell you exactly how many bytes to receive for the actual payload.

Now I'm no python expert but after googling around a bit I think something like

```
def receive_image()
    lengthBytes = sock.recv(4)
    length = struct.unpack("!i", lengthBytes)[0]

    data = sock.recv(length)
```

*Note: After reading John Gordon's comment on the question I guess this still doesn't fully solve the waiting until according buffers are actually filled - as said no python expert - but I hope it gives you a idea where to go ;)*